# How to remove an element with HTML DOM?

Tags: javascript, phantomjs, casperjs, simple-html-dom

I get the data from website http://www.u-movie.com.tw/page.php?page_type=now&portal=cinema&ver=tw with CasperJS.

I want to remove `<p>` that there is no id.

So i try to select the root and remove it, but it will show `null is not an object`

If i don't use jQuery just only javascript how do i fix it ?

Any help would be appreciated.

Here is part of my document:
[image]

Here is my code:

```
function getMovieTime() {
    this.evaluate(function () {
        var time = document.querySelectorAll('ul.posts p');
        time.parentNode.remove();
        time = document.querySelectorAll('ul.posts');
        return Array.prototype.map.call(time, function (e) {
            return e.innerText;
        });
    });
};
```

I call getMovieTime():  this code report null

```
var movieTime = [];  // global variable
casper.then(function () {
    movieTime = this.evaluate(getMovieTime);
});
```

Comment: For which line is the `null is not an object` reported?

Comment: I update my question, i call getMovieTime function cause reported null.

Comment: For which line is it reported?  for the `this.evaluate(function () {` ? It does not make sense that you call `this.evaluate(getMovieTime)` and then inside of the `getMovieTime` doing a `this.evaluate(function () {` again.

Comment: Yes... it's another point , thanks for remind.

Answer (score -1):

First,

> The method node.remove() is implemented in the DOM 4 specification.
>   But because of poor browser support, you should not use
>   it.

Then instead you can try replacing it instead.

Here

```
var parent = document.getElementById("latest_posts");
var child = document.getElementById("posts");
var para = document.createElement("p");
var node = document.createTextNode(" ");
para.appendChild(node);
parent.replaceChild(para,child);
```

**Note** -  you should use `getElementsByClassName` instead of `getElementById`

Comment: Thanks for your reply, but i can't understand it . Ther is no id in my document . how can i complete it from your code ? `getElementById`

Comment: Based on the tags and the code shown in the question the `remove` is used context of phantomjs, so browser support does not really matter as long as the current version of phantomjs supports it.

Comment: And where does the OP use `getElementsByClassName` or `getElementById`. The code shows only `querySelectorAll` and `.getElementById("latest_posts")` would be wrong, because the element has the class `latest_posts`

Comment: @t.niese. I mentioned that he should ideally use getElementsByClassName  under note. This was just an example of a replace. Also, not aware of casper or phantom. Therefore didn't corrected the original code

Comment: So i should use `getElementsByClassName` instead of `querySelectorAll` and try to use your code step by step , right ?

Comment: My idea was to point you to use` replace` instead of `remove`. You can keep using querySelectorAll

Comment: Not solve it yet , i will try to solve it , thanks for your sugesstion @kushalvm